# Why do we always need to check if an object has a key? - JS

Tags: javascript

I have the codes below.

```
var obj = {
  name : 'Krysten',
  age : 33,
  hasPets : false
};

function listAllValues(obj) {
  // your code here
  var array = [];
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = obj[key];
        array.push(value);
    }
}
  console.log(array);

}

listAllValues(obj);
```

I want to focus on this code:

```
for(key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    }
}
```

Why do we always need to check if `obj` has its own property key?
It doesn't sounds clear to me. Anyone who can explain it to me in laymans term?
Sorry dummy here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` checks is the `property` of the object's itself. It may also be a property of it's **prototype**. So with that you check if the property belongs to the current object, not it's prototype.

**Example**

I have an `object`, which has a `prototype`. With pure `for in` it prints all properties, also that ones which are in the `prototype` (id). But with the second one, it prints only that ones which belongs to the object itself.

```js
var parent = {
    id: 1
};

var obj = {
   name: 'Test',
   age: 18
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, parent);

// All properties, also the prototype's. See the `id` property
console.log('All properties');
for(var key in obj){
    console.log(key);
}

console.log('Only it\'s properties');
// All properties that belong only to object
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a remnant from darker times, when JS wasn't that sleek and its developers more coarse. When everybody [extended basic prototypes](http://prototypejs.org/) and we didn't have the ability to [define non-enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute).

So you never knew what properties ended up on your objects due to inheritance; that's when we introduced this practice of checking wether it's an own property. That's also where it started to be considered a bad practice to extend foreign prototypes.

But these were rougher, darker times. Times when you needed mental strength to write JS. When you needed wisdom to write a function that worked in multiple browser, and nerves of steel to approach or even modify someone elses code never knowing what bain you may bring upon you

Nowadays I'd immediately abandon a foreign lib that would be so ruthless to randomly modify the basic prototypes *(with very few exceptions)*, especially if it doesn't make these extensions `enumerable:false`.